# How to select unique albums in sqlLite database

Tags: database, sqlite, select, unique, distinct

I have a database with mp3 info in it. I need to select unique albums... but make sure that if the album artists are different with same album titles... they are kept separate...

Is this possible with a select statement?

I tried to GROUP, but it either groups the albums... and if 2 albums are the same, with different artists... they are grouped... or if I group by artist, the albums stay unique, but not all albums show as they just show one album per artist.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by both:

```
select album, artist
from mp3s
group by album, artist
```